# Type AnyObject? does not conform to protocol CVarArgType?

Tags: swift, nspredicate

I am trying to dynamically generate a predicate and getting a compile error after updating from beta version of Xcode. Any idea what the problem is. I tried casting the result of valueForKey to CVarArgType with no luck.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class User: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var a: String?
    @NSManaged var b: String?
}


var user = User() // This will probably crash, but good enough to reproduce compile error
var keys = ["a", "b"]

for key in keys {
    var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", key, user.valueForKey(key))
}
```

Comment: Where is the error being reported? Also, can you at least give a fake declaration for `keys` that still reproduces the error? Also, how a fake declaration for managedObject would be great. The easier it is for people to test out your code and reproduce the problem (especially in a playground) the better answers you will get.

Comment: @Bluehound %@ should not be used for attribute names in a predicate

Comment: @drewag Exception is on valueForKey call. I have a comment in the code that says keys is an array of strings ["property1", "property2"]

Comment: You're right. I just looked at it and thought strong format specifiers not predicate format specifiers

Comment: @aryaxt, I am saying that if you can give us a code block we can literally copy and paste into a playground and get the error, we can help you much more effectively and quickly.

Comment: @drewag Updated code so that it can be reproduced in playground

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `managedObject.valueForKey(key)` is returning an optional value. You are going to have to validate that it is returning a value first:

```
if let value = managedObject.valueForKey(key) {
    var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", key, value )
    predicates.append(predicate)
}
```

The other problem is that you are trying to pass an AnyObject as the parameter. You can also add an optional cast to NSObject to the if-let and that should fix your compiler error:

```
if let value = user.valueForKey(key) as? NSObject {
    var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", key, value)
}
```

Comment: Still same issue. I also tried force unwrap, will provide sample playground code in a sec

Comment: Still getting the same compile error. Are you running the latest version of Xcode? My code used to work until I updated to the latest version

Comment: @aryaxt, sorry, my playground was acting up. You also need to cast the resulting value to a String. See my updated answer.

Comment: `... as? NSObject` might work as well and is not restricted to string properties.

Comment: But the value is not necessarily a string. You could have a predicate that checks against an NSNumber or an NSManagedObject for example "address == %@", user.address